# Getting python error Arrays were different lengths in a for loop using len

Tags: python

I have created a dictionary to put there the percentage of utilization for each reference.

```
references=[pack_data["actual_box_barcode"].unique().tolist()]
ref_utilization={}
```

Now to get each utilization ratio I do:

```
total_utilization=len(pack_data["actual_box_barcode"])
    for i in references:
        ref_filtered = pack_data[pack_data["actual_box_barcode"] == i]
        ref_utilizations=len(ref_filtered["actual_box_barcode"])
        ref_utilization[i]=ref_utilizations/total_utilizations
```

However I am getting this 
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 2264084 vs 41

Which I don't get as the division is between 2 numeric variables.
Do you know what could be happening?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try removing list wrapper while defining `references` -

```
references = pack_data["actual_box_barcode"].unique().tolist()
```

Comment: Didn't work. Funny thing is that if I do this with direct references instead of the for loop it works. This works but I want to do it for all of the refs
references=[pack_data["actual_box_barcode"].unique()]
ref_utilization={}
total_utilization=len(pack_data["actual_box_barcode"])
print(total_utilization)
ref_filtered=pack_data[pack_data["actual_box_barcode"]=="BG2"]
ref_utilizations=len(ref_filtered["actual_box_barcode"])